How to filter the loaded data when zooming in on a plot?
I am a newbie with TIBCO Spotfire. I have a connection to Databricks table to get the data from. However, the size of my dataset is huge nearly 100 millions rows. when I externally load the data, and I plot a line chart of one of my columns vs. Time, the Spotfire is not rendering well. and it takes some time to zoom in, zoom out and do other processes.
right now, I am interested to visualize the data and zoom in on the data in different time intervals. is there a way to load only that part of time interval to speed up of the visualization?
I searched for this issue, and I think maybe using "data on-demand" may be a solution but don't know exactly how it works.
